# PHP empty($string) return true but string is not empty

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
$m->type = 'EVENT';
if (empty($m->type)) {
  var_dump($m->type);
}
?>
```

This piece of code prints

```
string(5) "EVENT"
```

How is this possible?

**edit**

The $m object is a plain one, with magic __set and __get that store values into a protected array.

```
<?php
$m->type = 'EVENT';
if ($m->type == NULL) {
  var_dump($m->type);
}
?>
```

The above mentioned code works as expected (it skips the if body).

Comment: Doesn't do that for me, I'm afraid (PHP 5.3.24)

Comment: Have you tried storing that string into a variable and then testing it? Like this: $string = $m->type; if(empty($string)){ //code here }

Comment: Try `$someVar=$m->type; if (empty($someVar)) {
  var_dump($m->type);
}` and tell us, what you get

Comment: What is `$m`?  (ie: what class?)  This doesn't happen with a `stdClass`, so the type of `$m` is probably a pretty big factor.

Comment: Is this the only piece of the code or have you just posted a subset? If there is more, a larger context may help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using magic getter within your class, [the docs page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#93117) documents a rather tricky behaviour:

```
<?php
class Registry
{
    protected $_items = array();
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_items[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_items[$key])) {
            return $this->_items[$key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

$registry = new Registry();
$registry->empty = '';
$registry->notEmpty = 'not empty';

var_dump(empty($registry->notExisting)); // true, so far so good
var_dump(empty($registry->empty)); // true, so far so good
var_dump(empty($registry->notEmpty)); // true, .. say what?
$tmp = $registry->notEmpty;
var_dump(empty($tmp)); // false as expected
?>
```

Comment: I think this may be what's affecting my code. I'll check it out.

Comment: so use `empty($m = $m->type)` instead of `empty($m->type)`, and it will work correctly

Comment: @Roman please don't, inline assignments are classical code smell.